Famous sequence generated from a figure
Each of the four figures generate a number sequence. Replace the question mark with the correct number sequence. Explain your reasoning.
       \
      \ \
     \ \ \       = 1 5 10 10 5
    \ \ \ \
   \ \ \ \ \
  
           


       /
      / /
     / / /       = 5 10 10 5 1
    / / / /
   / / / / /
  



        |
       | |
      | | |      = 1 1 5 4 9 4 5 1 1
     | | | |
    | | | | |
   



        —
       — —
      — — —      =   ?
     — — — —
    — — — — —


The answer could be

the sequence 16,8,4,2,1.

Indeed, consider

rows 0 to 4 of the Pascal's triangle:

    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1

Now, for each of the pictures in question, sum left-to-right
the triangle's entries along the lines given in the picture.

That, in detail, gives:

(but note that the lines I draw below are separators, the lines
of numbers they produce correspond to the lines in the pictures)

Figure 1:

    1
   1\1
  1\2\1
 1\3\3\1
1\4\6\4\1

where, left-to-right, the sums are 1,5,10,10,5.

Figure 2:

    1
   1/1
  1/2/1
 1/3/3/1
1/4/6/4/1

where, left-to-right, the sums are 5,10,10,5,1.

Figure 3:

       |1|
     |1| |1|
   |1| |2| |1|
 |1| |3| |3| |1|
1| |4| |6| |4| |1

where, left-to-right, the sums are 1,1,5,4,9,4,5,1,1.

Finally, figure 4:

    1
   ---
   1 1
  -----
  1 2 1
 -------
 1 3 3 1
---------
1 4 6 4 1

where, left-to-right (i.e. bottom to top, since the bottom
line is the one with the left-most entry, and so on),
the sums are 16,8,4,2,1.


Well explained! However the intended answer was the one tToE gave, hence why I wrote "famous" to exclude the descending sequence. Although I understand the logic behind your answer (starting with the left-most) ofc so this answer work. I'm giving the tick to you since you explained it in more detail.

Thank you, feedback appreciated.  I had missed that hint...

The answer is:

 1 2 4 8 16 
 It's the famous sequence: power of 2

The reason is:

 The number of terms in the previous three sequences hints that each symbol should signify a digit.
 And we can easily derive the digits in all positions as below:
 
     1
    1 1
   1 2 1
  1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1



I don't see how you go from triangles to sequences, can you explain in a little more detail.

What is the significance of the different line directions?

Yes, this is the correct answer, but a more clear explanation is missing. So try to explain it in more detail (the different orientations of the line)
